# test on a value of a Kafka stream position

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I want to test on a value of a Kafka stream position
if the equal value has for example "2"
then display start function A else start function B

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'video-group',
    'fetch.message.max.bytes': '15728640',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'largest'})
# Group ID is completely arbitrary

lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
 flag = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda v : v[0])

if  flag == "2":
    A = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda v: v[1])
    A.pprint()
else:
    lines.pprint()
```

Answer (score 0):

`flag == "2"` will never be true because that's a Spark RDD object, not a singular string.

Plus, Kafka has a continuous stream of records, potentially, so just checking the second column of that first record (assuming you called collect() function) wouldn't work either.

If you want to check for the 2 of any row, you would have to filter it

```
lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
flag = lines.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).filter(lambda columns: columns[1] == "2")
flag.pprint()
```

If you want to just consume Kafka using Python and check the record values, you don't need Spark